# Показать Django-проект

Tags: django

Вот создал я определённое django-powered приложение и хочу теперь, чтобы некоторые мои друзья на него могли посмотреть. Можно ли это сделать, используя стандартный `runserver`? Если да -- то как, если нет -- то почему?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Именно показать некоторым друзьям можно и с использованием runserver. Но для какого-либо даже минимального использования runserver  не  предназначен.
Но чтобы показать друзьям, всё равно нужен сервер. А где сервер, там и апач настраивается достаточно легко.

Кстати, погуглите руководство, как выгрузить проект на heroku. Оно есть и на самом сервисе, и во множестве блогов. Рассмотрите этот вариант, для того, чтобы показать друзьям он более чем удачен.

Comment: У меня как бы даже до ближайшего релиза всё очень далеко, мне нужно просто показать 2-3 человекам то, что у меня уже есть, и всё. Про heroku -- спасибо, взял на заметку на будущее.

Answer (score 2):

В роутере делай проброс порта (вроде http://dlink.ru/ru/faq/246/1156.html).
Внешний 80, внутренний 8000, укажи локальный ip-адрес твоего компьютера.

Проект запускай `manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000` .

Друзьям дай ссылку `http://ip-роутера/`

Comment: 404 по ссылке

Comment: зависит от роутера. если 404 отдал сам роутер, а не джанга - используй 8000 как внешний порт и ссылку с указанием порта.

Comment: я имею ввиду, по ссылке, которую ты дал

Answer (score 1):

Можно, если у Вас прямое подключение к Сети. Для этого сервисом типа whatsmyip смотрите свой IP-адрес, запускаете manage.py runserver ВАШ_IP:8000, и друзья могут зайти по этому адресу (`http://ВАШ_IP:8000`).

Также можно зарегистрироваться в amazon web services или heroku и бесплатно получить минимальную конфигурацию, которой вполне хватит на показ друзьям.

Comment: Я пробовал так сделать, но на меня рансервер вот так ругнулся: "Error: That IP address can't be assigned-to." В инет выхожу через вай-фай роутер.

Comment: Значит, не напрямую, значит, не получится так.

Comment: Придётся регаться на heroku(